# Update column as update from 01-01-21 to 15-01-21 and so on as on after each 15 days it will change from dbms range

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

What I have is this:

```
VI_ID   DP_DATE EMPLOYEE_ID QTY   PRATE

    1/1/2020    10000001    33          
    1/2/2020    10000001    30          
    1/3/2020    10000001    31          
    1/4/2020    10000001    34          
    1/5/2020    10000001    30          
    1/6/2020    10000001    30          
    1/7/2020    10000001    33          
    1/8/2020    10000001    31
```

What I want is this:

```
VI_ID   DP_DATE         EMPLOYEE_ID QTY   PRATE

    1/1/2020    10000001    33            30
    1/2/2020    10000001    30            30
    1/3/2020    10000001    31            30
    1/4/2020    10000001    34            30
    1/5/2020    10000001    30            32
    1/6/2020    10000001    30            32 
    1/7/2020    10000001    33            32 
    1/8/2020    10000001    31            32
```

Like here it changes after 4 days. What can I add in this code which can gives me my desire?

```
update DAILY_PRODUCTION
set PRATE = floor(dbms_random.value(30, 35))
```

In this list, there is a lot other employees, also dbms will gives each employee random number and that will same for all date for 15 days remain after 15 days it will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up of sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_production
AS
        SELECT DATE '2021-1-1' + LEVEL - 1            AS dp_date,
               10000001                               AS employee_id,
               FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (30, 35))     AS qty,
               CAST (NULL AS NUMBER)                  AS prate
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 60;
```

Then by using a `MERGE` statement, you can update the data as you had described. The example below will change the `prate` every 4 days. If you modify the 3 `MOD` statements from 4 to 15, then the prate will change every 15 days. Note that this will only work if there are no gaps within the dates since the query is using `ROWNUM`. You can also modify the `WHERE` clause on the inner select if you only want the changes to affect a specific date range.

```sql
MERGE INTO daily_production dp
     USING (SELECT dp_date,
                   CASE
                       WHEN MOD (ROWNUM - 1, 4) > 0
                       THEN
                           LAG (prate, MOD (ROWNUM - 1, 4)) OVER (ORDER BY dp_date)
                       ELSE
                           prate
                   END    AS prate
              FROM (  SELECT dp_date,
                             CASE
                                 WHEN MOD (ROWNUM, 4) = 1 THEN FLOOR (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (30, 35))
                             END    AS prate
                        FROM daily_production
                       WHERE dp_date >= DATE '2021-1-1' AND dp_date <= DATE '2021-1-20'
                    ORDER BY dp_date)) d
        ON (dp.dp_date = d.dp_date)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET dp.prate = d.prate;
```

Comment: O boy I thing you solved my matter I am not at this time on System after Check I will Let to Know You Thanks for your Precious time and work Best Regards

Comment: its worked on [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=570a133b6fd72fe82f63c6384e0abf83](dbfiddle) i checked just one question is it work with all Employee_ID which are in this table Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will change for every 4 rows for the entire table, no matter what the `employee_id` is

Comment: Bundle of Thanks Dear @EJ Egyed

Comment: hi @EJ Egyed  it throw me this error `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` ok we can get it by 'distinct' but there is also i needed with all duplicate row same because its daily production table and in each date there are many employees which production will be set so agt one date there are many record or many employees id and i have to update all with same type and for the date not same for every one for employeeid same for 15  days Thanks for advance please help me for this its urgent